# Prove $\binom{n}{k+1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}$.

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, binomial-coefficients

For $n = 0,1,2,...$ and $k \in \{0,...,n\}$, prove that
$$\binom{n}{k+1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}$$

Here's my attempt.
$$\binom{n}{k+1}+\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-(k+1))!(k+1)!} + \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$
$$\implies \frac{n!(n-k)}{(n-(k+1))!(k+1)!(n-k)} + \frac{n!(k+1)}{(n-k)!k!(k+1)}$$
$$\implies \frac{n!(n-k)+n!(k+1)}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}$$
$$\implies \frac{n!((n-k)+(k+1))}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}$$
$$\implies \frac{n!(n+1)}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}$$
But I get stuck here because this does not equal $\binom{n+1}{k}$ but instead equals $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.

Comment: Indeed, the right-hand side of the identity is ${n+1 \choose k+1}$. Your proof looks correct.

Comment: Your proof is correct! Think about the case $n=1, k=0$.

Comment: Or, if $n$ is even, take $k=n/2$. Then $\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is indeed correct as the identity itself is wrong.
If you choose $k+1$ items out of $n+1$ items, you either choose all $k+1$ items from the first $n$ items, or choose $k$ items from the first $n$ items and choose the last item. Hence the right hand side must contain $k+1$ instead of $k$.